# Computing the probability of $P[ \sum_{i=1}^n X_i = k]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X_1, X_2, X_3,.., X_n$ be n i.i.d random variables taking values in $\{1,2,3,4,...\}$ such that $P[X_i = p] = \alpha_p$ for some known tuple of positive probabilities $(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3,...)$. Then given a positive integer $k$ how do we compute, $P[ \sum_{i=1}^n X_i = k]$ ?

---

Does this naturally lend itself to setting up of a recursion in $k$?

Comment: You are asking about the [discrete convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Discrete_convolution) of probability measures.

Answer (score 3):

One approach is via the probability generating function of the $X_i$: if we set
$$ \Phi_{X_1}(t)=\mathbb{E}[t^{X_1}]=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X_1=k)t^k $$
then since the $X_i$ are i.i.d. it follows that
$$ \Phi_{X_1+\dots+X_n}(t)=\Phi_{X_1}(t)^n$$
and the desired probability is the coefficient of $t^k$ in this power series. In general this will be a fairly complicated sum, but if you have a nice expression for $\Phi_{X_1}(t)$ things may simplify.

Comment: Thanks! Do you see any nice recursion in $k$?  ($k$ as I had defined and not your $k$!)

Comment: Not for $n$ fixed, but by considering the possible values $X_n$ takes you can get a recursion involving $X_1+\dots+X_{n-1}$ and $k$.

Comment: Can you maybe write that down?

Comment: Sure: $\mathbb{P}(X_1+\dots+X_n=k)=\sum_{j=1}^{k-n+1}\mathbb{P}(X_n=j)\mathbb{P}(X_1+ \dots+X_{n-1}=k-j)$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am just wondering what exactly was the benefit of this probability generating function approach here. What did one gain? Isn't this equation saying nothing more than the brute-force statement "look at all the solutions in positive integers of the equation $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i =k$ and add up the probabilities for each of the solution where for each solution the probability is the product of the corresponding $\alpha$s" ?

Comment: Depending on the distribution of $X_1$, it could be that there is a simple expression for $\Phi_{X_1}(t)$, which would make computing the coefficients of $\Phi_{X_1}(t)^n$ much easier than just using a brute force approach.